# how solve this error while running a script command in VS code for deploying a solidity smart contract on Foundry?

Tags: solidity

I am getting this error while running a solidity script inside VS code for deploying a solidity smart contract "SimpleStorage" on Foundry.

````
Error: 
contract source info format must be `<path>:<contractname>` or `<contractname>`
user@user:~/src$ forge script script/lib/forge-std/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol```

I found the lib/forge-std library was missing from my installation as I could not find it by exploring on top right.So subsequently installed it by creating Lib folder and then pasted forge-std inside it. I guess wrong path of folder could be the cause of this error. Please help how to set it correctly. 

I tried resolving it by copying the DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol and SimpleStorage.sol inside various folders and subfolders but could not make it work.
````

Comment: Try running `forge install` as that should add forge-std since it is a base package.

Answer (score 0):

The script you are trying to run should be in the project directory `/scripts`. 
The command should therefore be: 
`forge script ./script/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol`

The lib directory is for packages you install (any github repository) using `forge install [github-username]/[github-repo-name]`, not code you run.

Answer (score -1):

The file extension .s.sol seems to be incorrect for a Solidity smart contract file. Solidity contract files typically have a .sol extension. For instance, if your contract is named DeploySimpleStorage, the file should be named something like DeploySimpleStorage.sol. Please double-check the extension of your contract file and ensure it follows the standard .sol extension for Solidity source code files.

If you intend for DeploySimpleStorage to be a script, it's important to provide it with an appropriate file extension specific to scripts. You should use extensions like .js for JavaScript or .ts for TypeScript to indicate that the file contains script code rather than Solidity contract code.

Comment: .s.sol is the standard extension for a forge solidity script.